# URLs Redirect To Another Page before redirecting the the URL

Tags: php, url, redirect, ads

I have been learning Objective-C for over two years, and I can't code PHP. I just wanted to know how I can redirect the user once he has entered his URL to another page with adverts on it, and then after 5 seconds redirect him to the entered URL. Please can you supply code, as I am not familiar with PHP at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John's suggestion sounds like a good one.

As for the code, to redirect in PHP, use:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

To get the parameter from the URL, you can use PHP's `$_GET` function:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

If your URL is http://www.example.com/?url=google.com, then you will be able to get the "google.com" using the above code.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

To put it together, try:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
header('Location: $url');
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect him to "http://MyPageWithAdverts.company.com?redirectUrl=*enteredUrl*". Let the adverts page sleep for five seconds, then redirect to it's "`redirectUrl`" parameter.

Comment: would you mind giving me some code for that as I said in the op I dont know any php!

Answer (score 1):

First you should be aware that the user inputs (like user input for URL) should be in a form.

You can redirect the user using the header function. Example:

```
header('Location: http://mydomain.com/lalala/index.php');
```

You can also put the URL on a variable like:

```
$url = 'http://mydomain.com/lalala/index.php';
```

Then,

```
header("Location: '".$url."'");
```

That's it for redirection. For a certain pause of 5 seconds, you can use the sleep function and the like or you can use javascript. For php, here is the sleep function you need:

```
sleep(5); // where 5 is the number of seconds.
```

thanks

Comment: ok I am currently redirecting to http://nucleusiphone.com/adverts/index.php/?url=http://google.com. How can I access the ?url=.... part?

Comment: that part is stored on a $_GET variable that is: $_GET['url'] = 'http://google.com' . You can access that url through that $_GET['url'] variable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When they first come in to, say, `http://example.com/somepage`, show them the ads page and include a refreshing `<meta>` tag like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://example.com/somepage?ads=0">
```

That should send them to `http://example.com/somepage?ads=0` after five seconds. You can use a simple `ads=0` CGI parameter to tell the server not show the ads or you can do similar things with a flag in a cookie. When `/somepage` gets hit without the cookie or without `?ads=0` then show them the ads, if the cookie is set or `?ads=0` is there then show them the real stuff.

You can also do it in JavaScript by setting a timer and redirecting by assigning to `window.location`.

This sort of thing can be defeated pretty easily but it should be sufficient for the casual browser.

Answer (score -1):

fix this code for redirect to another URL

```
<?php
  $url = $_GET['url'];  //Get URL
  if($url==""){         // Check URL isn't empty
    echo("Not URL");
  }else{
    echo("Goto: ".$url);
    header('Location: '.$url); // goto URL
  }
  sleep(5); // where 5 is the number of seconds.
?>
```